# Webpack Images for production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

After a week of yelling at my monitor while configuring my vps for NGINX/Node, I have succeeded in getting my React app to run. I am all Javascripted out right now(two console errors away from an aneurysm), and would greatly appreciate some help with my webpack configuration.

*Currently* I have a src folder that gets build with webpack and thrown into a bundle.js file(the usual) in a dist folder. However, I do not think I am using webpack correctly, or at least to its full potential.

Since I am not an expert with Webpack yet, I currently have all my images already sitting inside the dist folder, and they are not run through webpack. I have a sneaking suspicion that this is the reason why my main "hero" image takes about a second to load when I visit the apps homepage, it is a very noticeable delay and unprofessional looking. Everything else works pretty blazing fast however.

I already have this loader setup for my images(no idea what this does, but I got it on the interwebz).

```
{
   test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/,
   loader: 'file-loader?emitFile=false&name=[path][name].[ext]'
}
```

Does anyone know what is considered good practice when dealing with images? I am just trying to prevent all of the calls to any images in my css from breaking if I implement this. Here is an example of my scss that successfully links to the dist/img/ folder

```
background: url('~/../img/hero.jpg');
```